# Moving to Netherlands: Student Residence Permit

Tags: visas, schengen, customs-and-immigration, netherlands, study

I am a US citizen who has received a Residence permit for the Netherlands because I am studying at a university there for two years.
I have bought my plane ticket, but I am worried that I will be asked to show my Visa for the Netherlands at the airport when leaving the USA with a one-way ticket.

The only 'proof' I have right now is the letter to the Dutch Immigration service that says I have been accepted to get the Residence Permit (and it's written in Dutch).

Is this a silly worry? Would an airline keep me from boarding just because I don't have the physical Residence Permit?

### Thank you all for your help.

Thank you all for the answers and comments, I already love this community more and more. It is so interesting to hear everyone's perspectives and stories!

Comment: Just to clarify, you're saying that you have a letter written by your university to the Dutch Immigration service saying you've been accepted? And nothing else from the immigration service?

Comment: Hello, so I have paperwork that says I have been accepted to the University as well as the immigration letter I mentioned. I suppose I am worried that the airlines would want an 'official visa'? (The residence permit is to be picked up in person in NL.)

Comment: Have you called your airline to see what they require?

Comment: Leaving the USA should not be an issue - many people depart on one-way tickets for a varirty of reasons (flexibility, cost). On arrival in the Netherlands, the Immigration Officer will see and read the Dutch correspondence and if in doubt may phone the Uni. Bear in mind at the start of term (if that's when you're arriving) there will be many international students doing the same thing so IOs will be very familiar with the process.

Comment: @GregHewgill the US is on a short list of countries whose citizens can travel to the Netherlands for the purpose of applying for a residence permit without a type D visa.  Germany has a similar system.

Comment: Timatic does not say proof of onward/return travel is required for USA citizens going to NL. Indeed, no airline has ever asked me for this on a flight to the Schengen Zone. At the NL border, your letter should be all you need, if you are asked anything at all.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus I suspect, however, that most of the airlines that flew you into the Schengen zone also had your reservation for a flight out of the Schengen zone, most likely on the same booking.

Comment: @phoog Not at all. Just flew in on Norwegian Air and out on a completely separate ticket for Aer Lingus.

Answer (score 2):

As a US citizen, you can travel 90 days visa-free to the Schengen area *for tourism, etc.* That should be sufficient for the American airline. How soon you want to leave is a Dutch concern.